# $apply unknown provider error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i'm trying to build a very simple chat with `express.js`, `socket.io` and `angular`. it works. the only problem that i have is when the socket message event is fired it isn't synchronizing and rendering it onto the page.

```
 var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');



angular.module('chat',[]).controller('chatController',['$scope','$apply',function($scope,$apply){
    chat = $scope;
    chat.messages = [];

    socket.on('messages',function(data){
        chat.$apply(function(){
            chat.messages.push(data);
        });
    });
}])
```

i know i should use $apply somehow but it gives me an error of unknow provider.
what is the correct way for implementing `$apply`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to pass $apply as a dependency,

Try this

```
angular.module('chat',[]).controller('chatController',['$scope',function($scope){
     $scope.messages = [];
     socket.on('messages',function(data){
         $scope.$apply(function(){
             $scope.messages.push(data);
        });
    });
}])
```